# Does "-dndebug" (lowercase) do anything in g++?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm working on minor changes to a multi-platform C++ project with a 400-line Linux [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile) that someone else created years ago.

Two lines in the makefile use `-dndebug` (lower-case) as a command-line argument to g++.
I think the intention was to define the `ndebug` symbol, but does the argument even do anything when it's lowercase?

I have minimal knowledge of g++ and [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), but, going by the page *[Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)*, I think the argument needs to be uppercase to work.

Comment: gcc indeed have `-d` option, but it is for debugging compiler passes itself. You don't need it. And even if it was intended, `-dndebug` is not valid (but e.g. `-da` is). So I suppose it should be `-DNDEBUG`, but someone messed it up.

Comment: To anyone editing this question: I think an edit that changed "dndebug" to "DNDEBUG" in the title was inappropriate, as the whole point of the question was to ask whether it does anything in lower-case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fairly easy to test:

#### Test program *test.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#ifdef TEST_DEFINE
    std::cout << "defined" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

#### Result

```
$ g++ -o 1 -DTEST_DEFINE test.cpp
$ ./1
defined
$ g++ -o 2 -dTEST_DEFINE test.cpp
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: T [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: E [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: S [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: T [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: _ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: E [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: F [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: E [enabled by default]
$ ./2
$
```

So as you can see, the [-d](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-d) option actually causes compiler warnings, so it looks like [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) is what was intended.

Comment: Ah, that explains the four warnings I see near the end of the make process. I had not linked those warnings to that argument, though I'm surprised that "e" and "u" are the only characters appearing as unrecognised. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, it should be upper case like this `-DNDEBUG`.

[`-D`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) is the GCC option to define a macro. [`NDEBUG`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) is the macro to be defined to turn off asserts as mandated by the C standard.

> I have minimal knowledge of g++ and [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), but, going by the page *[Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)*, I think the argument needs to be uppercase to work.

As for `-dndebug`, since macros are case-sensitive, I think it will not have any effect i.e. it should get ignored, unless there is some code you have that references it.